# Convert an initializer_list object to unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map, initializer-list

A simple initializer list can be converted to the corresponding array object easily (for purposes to pass an explicit list to a function as an argument):

First, we have a function that takes array as an input

```
float f(const int *x) {...}
```

Now we also make an instance that takes initializer list instead

```
float f(const std::initializer_list<int> x) { return f(x.begin()); }
```

And it works!

```
std::cout << f({1,2,3});
```

Now I'd like to do the same with unordered_map (I want to use the specific feature of the unordered map that it takes the argument as a key and it spits out the corresponding value), i.e. to be able to do something like:

```
std::cout << f({ {"x",1}, {"y", 2}, {"z", 3} });
```

I've gotten this far:

```
float f(const std::unordered_map<std::string, int>) {...}
float f(const std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, int>> x) { return f(???); }
```

How do I convert an initializer list of pairs into the corresponding unordered map? Is this THE way to do it, or is there a complication that prevents this from working (like, say, that unordered_map is not simply a list of pairs, but rather complicated thing that involves hashing)? I don't see why this chokes, however, as we casually initialize unordered maps explicitly with lists of pairs, so I don't quite see why there isn't any natural conversion between the two.

Comment: Why use the overload at all here? If you want to end up with `std::unordered_map` regardless, why not just stick with one function with the signature of `float f(const std::unordered_map<std::string, int>) {...}`?

Comment: okay, but float f(const std::unordered_map<std::string, int>) does not take an initializer list as an argument, i.e. f({{"x",3},{"y",5}}) complains that "no instance of overloaded function matches the arguments". If I add an overloaded version with initializer list, now it doesn't complain about the arguments, but I don't know how to convert an initializer list to unordered map.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/oKhv4b). This compiles on lastest Clang, GCC and MSVS. What is your language version?

Comment: Not the answer, but I suggest passing `unordered_map` by a const reference, not by value.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 (v141), SDK version 10.0.17763.0. I'm not quite sure how to check the version of c++

Comment: Oh my god. There was an error on my part! It actually works with unordered_map! It doesn't work for me with just a list (f (const float*) using as f({1,2,3}) throws an error "illegal indirection"), but luckily, it works with unordered_map now...

Comment: @user16320 A pointer cannot be initialized a braced-init-list of integers.